# Connecting VBA with oracle 11g enterprise edition

Tags: oracle, vba, excel, database-connection, connection-string

I am trying to connect VBA to Oracle  11 g- I was checking whether the connection string was fine.

While trying below code I am getting error while opening the connection.

> Runtime error-3706 Application defined  or object -defined error.

Can anyone help?

**Code:**

```
Sub getdatafromOracle()
Dim connectdb As ADODB.Connection

connectdb.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER= OraOLEDB.Oracle;DATA SOURCE=DBname;USER ID=uname;PASSWORD=Pword"

connectdb.Open
connectdb.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: What about the space character between `PROVIDER=` and `OraOLEDB.Oracle;`, remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You habe to initialize the Connection object before you can use it.

```
set connectdb = New ADODB.Connection
```

Maybe you have to use this syntax (I am not sure):

```
connectdb.Open("PROVIDER=OraOLEDB.Oracle;DATA SOURCE=DBname", "uname", "Pword")
```

Comment: I missed while pasting here- i have already initialized the connection. still it didnt worked out.